# Generalized Induction Verification

Tags: elementary-number-theory, proof-verification, induction

Consider the following simple exercise.

> Prove or disprove: $\gcd(km, kn) = k \gcd(m, n)$, where $m, n, k$ are natural numbers.

Now, this is easy to prove using prime factorization. Knowing that this proposition was true, I decided to try and prove it just using induction and the Euclidean algorithm.

I only recently learned about generalized induction, so I was wondering if someone could look this over and tell me if it is valid or not.

> Since the $\gcd$ function is symmetric with respect to its arguments, we can assume without loss of generality that $m \le n$. We proceed by strong induction using a lexicographical ordering $(<<)$ on $\mathbb{N}^2$.
>
> For $m = n = 0$, the result is trivial. Assume true for all $(m', n') < < (m, n)$. Then
>   \begin{align*}
>  k\gcd(m, n) &= k \gcd(n \!\!\!\!\mod m, m) & \textit{By the Euclidean algorithm}\\
>  &= \gcd( k (n \!\!\!\!\mod m), k m) & \textit{By induction}\\
>  &= \gcd( k n \!\!\!\!\mod k m, k m) & \textit{Property of mod function} \\
>  &= \gcd( k m, k n) & \textit{By the Euclidean algorithm}\\
>  \end{align*}
>   The reader will forgive the slight abuse of notation: $n \!\!\mod m = n - m \lfloor n / m\rfloor$. Thus the result holds for all pairs of natural numbers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your proof is very close. The problem is with the base case. You cannot take a number modulo $0$, and you do not eliminate the possibility that $m=0$. Instead of proving just the case $(m',n')=(0,0)$ (and is that trivial by the way? ... I have never seen anyone take the GCD of $0$ and $0$), I would take as base case all $(0,n)$ for $n\in\mathbb{N}$. This is easy since $$k\gcd(0,n)=kn, \quad\gcd(k\cdot0,k\cdot n)=\gcd(0,kn)=kn.$$ Now the next case must have $m\ge 1$, so your proof follows through validly.

---

If this is your first time using strong induction, I have always found it very helpful to make things "concrete" to aid my understanding. I like to actually "visualize" the transition that happens from base case to case I, from case I to case II, etc. Your proof is a sort of "algorithm" which we can follow to make each transition.

Here, we have established the case $(0,0)$. Next in line is $(0,1)$. You proof tells us to write down $$k\gcd (0,1)=k\gcd (1\bmod 0,0)=\gcd(k\bmod (k0),k\cdot 0)$$ But already this is making no sense. What is $1\bmod 0$?

Now assume that we have strengthened our base knowledge to all $(0,n)$. Next in line is $(1,0)$. We write $$k\gcd(1,0)=k\gcd(0\bmod 1,1)$$ By induction (i.e. previous knowledge) this is $$\gcd(k\cdot 0\bmod 1,k\cdot 1)=\gcd(k\cdot 0\bmod (k\cdot 1),k\cdot 1)=\gcd(k\cdot 1,k\cdot 0)$$ and we have proven the case! You can see how each case follows naturally from a previous one.

Comment: Thanks, clearly my base case was not logical :) Also, definitley not my first time using strong induction, just using induction on a set that is not the natural numbers. But after thinking about it I see how it is really the exact same process.

Comment: @A.E Actually, I have sometimes wondered why "regular" induction is taught at all. The whole point of "generalized" induction is that you use all the prior knowledge available to you, or at least however much of it you need - only using the single previous instance amounts to withholding info... seems like a proving game to me!